How to embed credentials in the iframe tag in src and auto login the site
I have an iframe tag with some link as src, I am adding username and password for auto logging into the other site by passing credentials in the src, but when I click on the link of the iframe tag it is giving as connection timeout issue as shown in the image..,
image showing the issue

How can we auto login to source url in frame by passing the credentials in the url
I have seen the related questions in the stack overflow on this issue but didnt helped me, looking for help on this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.



